# The /dev directory contains the system devices. /dev/stdin is a link. To what does it point?

Tags: ls, devices, stdin

I'm playing around with terminal and found `stdin@` in /dev. Several questions here.

1) What does an item with an @ symbol at the end of it mean/suggest? When is it used?

2) As the question suggests, it is a link. What command can I use to figure out what this points to?

Comment: `lr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     0B Feb 24 01:03 /dev/stdin@ -> fd/0` is the output I get. It points to `fd/0`? Thanks to @user4556274 I got my answer. But now unsure regarding what `fd/0` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `@` indicates a symbolic link.  Your `ls` is probably an alias to `ls -F` (and additional flags).  If you unalias `ls` or explicitly execute `/bin/ls` you won't see the filetype decorations.
2. Execute `ls -l /dev/stdin` to see the target of the symbolic link.
3. On Linux, `/dev/stdin` links to `/proc/self/fd/0` (`/dev/stdin` is a link to `/dev/fd/0` and `/dev/fd` is a link to `/proc/self/fd`). `/proc/self` is a directory on [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) where the kernel exposes information about the calling process (i.e. each process gets information about itself when it reads from `/proc/self`). The subdirectory `fd` contains an entry for each [open file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) in the process, which is a (somewhat magic) symbolic link pointing to the file that the process has open.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. In my bash_profile: `alias ls='ls -GFh'`